# Why does this Java program compile on my computer with eclipse, but not any other computer with eclipse and JDK?

Tags: java, compilation

So, for an assignment I'm supposed to do a couple different thing using scanners. I'm supposed to get 4 doubles as input and output the average of the 4, then its going to ask for two inputs(a first and last name), and then take the length, first letters, and print the name with the first letter capitalized, and then take the Sin and Cos of a degree entered, and it's up to me to code the conversion.

The problem I'm getting is that when I compile it on my computer it works perfectly fine, but when I submit it online, or just open it on another computer, it gives me an error: Exception in thread "main"

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: **No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at Assignment2.main(Assignment2.java:39)**
```

I'm interpreting this as an error in line 39, which is bolded in my code below, but I have no idea what's actually wrong.

Haven't been able to go to my professors office hours because they're when i have a lab for a different class.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double in1;
    double in2;
    double in3;
    double in4;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input 4 numbers: ");
    in1 = in.nextDouble();
    in2 = in.nextDouble();
    in3 = in.nextDouble();
    in4 = in.nextDouble();
    in.nextLine();

    double average = (in1 + in2 + in3 + in4) / 4;
    System.out.print("The average of these four numbers is: "); 
    System.out.printf("%.2f" , average);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("What is your first name?: ");
        String firstName = in.nextLine(); //<----- this is where it tells me there is an error

    System.out.println("What is your last name: ");
        String lastName = in.nextLine();


    String firstAllCap = firstName.toUpperCase();
    String lastAllCap = lastName.toUpperCase();

    char first1 = firstAllCap.charAt(0);
    char last1 = lastAllCap.charAt(0);


    String firstNameCap = firstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + firstName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    String lastNameCap = lastName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + lastName.substring(1).toLowerCase();

    System.out.println("Your name is: " + firstNameCap + " " + lastNameCap);
    System.out.println("The first letter of the first name is: " + first1);
    System.out.println("The first letter of the Last name is: " + last1);
    int nameLength = firstName.length() + lastName.length();
    System.out.println("The length of your name is: " + nameLength);
    System.out.println("The intial letters are: " + first1 + last1);
    System.out.println("The last letter is: " + lastName.charAt(lastName.length()-1));
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Insert degree to evaluate cosine and sine: ");
    double degree = in.nextDouble();


    double radian = ((degree * Math.PI)/ 180);

    double sin = Math.sin(radian);
    double cos = Math.cos(radian);

    System.out.print("Sin(" + degree + "): ");
    System.out.printf("%.2f", sin);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Cos(" + degree + "): ");
    System.out.printf("%.2f", cos);
    System.out.println();

    in.close();
}
```

When i compile on my computer this is the output:

Input 4 numbers:

```
123
123
123
123
```

The average of these four numbers is: `123.00`

What is your first name?:

```
matt
```

What is your last name:

```
kaminski
```

Your name is: `Matt Kaminski`

The first letter of the first name is: `M`

The first letter of the Last name is: `K`

The length of your name is: `12`

The intial letters are: `MK`

The last letter is: i

Insert degree to evaluate cosine and sine:

```
21
```

Sin(21.0): `0.36`

Cos(21.0): `0.93`

Comment: `Exception in thread "main"` is not a compilation problem

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't picking up extra whitespace for the newline? That can sometimes cause a problem with Scanners.

Comment: I am no friend of traitorous Scanner. You left out all hasNext* checks. Instead of `nextLine` maybe `next` would do. Evidently they entered a name without newline. (`hasNextLine` false).

Answer (score 0):

i just tested the code and it looks like it works fine. however as per what i think it could be the way the online site provide inputs .

Maybe you should try to use in.next() instead of in.NextLine() and try to cast everything u want

it is possible that maybe the site is giving the input as 
12 12 12 12 Test middle 50

Comment: This worked on the online submission. Thank you so much for this. I originally thought it was a compilation error but a commenter above told me it wasn't and that completely blew my mind, and I was lost on what to fix. Now i'll remember that the submission needs to accommodate to inputs using spaces only.